# communication with local network from other network connection

Tags: mysql, reactjs, react-native, networking, phpmyadmin

First of all I'm really new to those internet connection properties I would try my best to explain the problem that I faced, hope you guys help on it thanks.

So at first, my network public IP is [175.139.x.x]. On this network, I have a NAS with IP [192.168.x.xxx] I have set up MySQL server in the NAS which will running phpMyAdmin database.

Now it came to the main point, I have develop an IOS app with react native in expo snack. The app will update or insert data into the database. So to doing that action, I have create some php script inside the WEB folder in the NAS [192.168.x.xxx] so in the react native code when I try to fetch the API I would do like this`fetch(http://192.168.x.xxx/api/insert.php)`,all of this function will works perfectly when the user is connect to the local network which the network with the public IP [175.139.x.x]. But when the user is using other internet connection or using it own mobile data the data would not send to the database. I have tried research on many article and website but I can't found the ways that can overcome this problem. here is the link to my code https://snack.expo.dev/KUjWAk491

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a typical use of Destination NAT . I hope you do have the privilege (otherwise have your network admin do so) to configure the WAN router. Basically, you want the router to pass the packet oringinally destined to a certain tcp port of your public address e.g 175.139.x.x:8080 ,instead to the tcp port 80 of your LAN address 192.168.x.xxx (as the http in the url **http://192.168.x.xxx/api/insert.php** use the default tcp port 80 ). That's to say , have the router perform a destination network address translation from 175.139.x.x:8080 to 192.168.x.xxx:80 . Surely, you will have to change the fetch to (http://175.139.x.x:8080/api/insert.php) . 
Note, in some cases, people from the internal network visit a LAN server  would still prefer to use the public adress + port (DNAT) to have the WAN router propagate traffic back to the detination LAN server for the sake of address consistency regardless of where the connection is initiated.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response ya correct i have to pass the data to the [175.139.x.x] but i have to said that the [192.168.x.xxx] is a ip address of a NAS, then the php script for insert the data into the database I have created inside a NAS folder 'WEB/api/' so if i change to fetch (175.139.x.x:8080/api/insert.php) this url it will not fetching the script, is it correct?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by **if i change to fetch (175.139.x.x:8080/api/insert.php) this url it will not fetching the script** . After the correct setting of DNAT on your WAN router, the traffic starting from the external network ( internet ) which is bound to 175.139.x.x:8080 will be passed to tcp port 80 of 192.168.x.xxx, then the upper layer of your NAS server will handle the /api/insert.php part .  This is like visiting  http://192.168.x.xxx/api/insert.php from LAN network, only this time it starts from the external network using the public ip plus a tcp port as its destination address.

Comment: By the way, please try not to use registered or well-known port on your public address such as  tcp 80 ,tcp 8080 etc.  , as they pose a security threat under online  port scanner. Usually a port number within a range between 50000 and 60000 can escape the instrusion more easily unless a full range scan is executed (which takes much more time and is rare).

Comment: <https://www.hillstonenet.com/support/4.5/en/preface.html#config_nat_conf_dnat.html> is this the correct way to set up DNAT?

Comment: I read the manual and it is a bit more complex than how I usually configure DNAT, but it shoud do the job. Just make sure you pay addtional attention to the bullet points from the manual listed below as they are the most crucial part. <br>**Creating an IP Mapping Rule** : step 6 to define the public ip address , step 7 to define the NAS(translated) address. <br>**Creating a Port Mapping Rule**:step 6 and 7 to define the public address and port(use a high numbered one like 5XXXX) , step 8 and 9 to define the NAS(translated) address and the port (tcp 80 in this case) respectively.

Comment: If you have never touched this kind of thing, please make a backup of your current configuration before your attempt. Restore from the backup immediately as opposed to try to fix things yourself if something terribly went wrong such as internet out of service. And if possible, please have a network admin do it for you.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for your information and advices probably I will discuss with my network admin :)